# KOMA-Script equal margins left and right with double sided

Tags: margins, koma-script, double-sided, printing, binding

I'm using [this KOMA-script-based template](https://github.com/novoid/LaTeX-KOMA-template) for a double-sided document.
To enforce that new chapters begin on an odd-numbered page, I set the corresponding option to `twoside`.
However, this also leads to the (to me) strange looking, unequal margins on the left vs. right side of the text. Similar to what's discussed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85884/koma-script-unequal-left-right-margin) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/553199/equal-left-and-right-hand-margins).

I understand the reason behind this margins, but I still don't like how it looks.
I will print some copies of the document, that's why I want new chapters on odd pages.
But most of the people will probably just read a PDF of the document - that's where the unequal margins look strange.

I also know that I can play with binding correction (BCOR) to adjust the margins a bit, but I'm not sure which value to choose.

What I'd like to have is a layout that prints all new chapters on odd pages but still has equal margins left and right.
What's the simplest and best way to do that?

Comment: Please don't link to external files. Someday the link might disappear and the question will become meaningless. Post the relevant bits *here*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you want to use option `twoside=semi`:

```latex
\documentclass[twoside=semi]{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}% dummy text
\usepackage{showframe}% show the page layout
\begin{document}
\chapter{Foo}
\lipsum[1-2]
\chapter{Bar}
\lipsum[3-10]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect, thanks!